# How to fix Line 15: error: expected expression before 'else'

Tags: c

I'm new to C language and would like to ask help on how to fix the said error on Line 15: error: expected expression before 'else'.

Thank You!

```
#include<stdio.h>

int n;

main()
{
    printf("Enter your age for qualification:");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    if (n >= 0 && n <= 100);
    {
        if (n <= 0);
        {
            printf("you're still in your mother's womb!");
        }
        else
        {
            (n >= 1 && n <= 17);
            printf("you're too young! you're not qualified!");
        }
        if (n >= 18 && n <= 100) {
            printf("you're qualified to vote");
        } else {
            (n >= 121);
            printf("that's impossible! you're already dead!");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if(n<=0);` <== lose the semi-colon. I have no idea what you hope `(n>=1 && n<=17);` is accomplishing. [Perhaps a good book on the C language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list?s=1|5.9428) may be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I'm trying to make a code for an age gate (eligibility to vote)

the (n>=1 && n<=17); is to show the message ("you're too young! you're not qualified!") when someone inputted ages 1 - 17. 

Unless I coded it wrong though, which is likely.

Thank you! :)

Comment: Please, bear in mind that 'semicolon' (`;`) can also be interpreted as an _empty statement_ ( if `n` is less or equal `0`, fine, we're done with condition checking ), so your `else` is left without its `if` that it depends on.   `else` without `if` doesn't exist in a valid C statement. (-:

Answer (score 1):

When you do e.g.

```
if(n<=0);
```

you have a single `if` statement that does *nothing*. And then the `else` is a stray keyword out of context.

The format of an `if` statement is

```
if (condition) statement
```

or

```
if (condition) statement else statement
```

Note that there is no semicolon after the condition, instead it's part of `statement`.

In your case with `if(n<=0);` the semicolon at the end is the `statement`, an empty statement.

Comment: It worked! I removed the semicolon, thanks to your answer.
So, there should always be no semicolon on "if" statements?

Comment: @NeoArcadia Not after the condition no.

Comment: Alright, I'll keep that in mind. Thank you kind sir ! :)

Answer (score 0):

To clear things out some more, your `if` statement would look something like this

```
if(n<=0)
    ;
```

That is an `if` with a blank line after that, hence nothing gets executed.

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include<stdio.h>

    int n;
    main()
    {
        printf("Enter your age for qualification:");
        scanf("%d",&n);

      if (n>=0 && n<=100)
      {
        if (n<=0)
        {
            printf("you're still in your mother's womb!");
        }
        else
        {
            /*(n>=1 && n<=17);*/
            printf("you're too young! you're not qualified!");
        }
        if(n>=18 && n<=100)
        {
            printf("you're qualified to vote");
        }
        else
        {
             /*(n>=121);*/
             printf("that's impossible! you're already dead!");
        }
      }

      return 0;  
    }
```

What your code should looks like, for example

Comment: Question, what does /* */ mean? Thank you! :)

Comment: It is used to add comment in the code. It will not be compiled and not executed. /* */ or begin line like //

Comment: It seems more likely they want it to be an else if condition, then a statement that does nothing.